# Is there have any plugin for comment word automatic completion in JetBrains' IDE?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, jetbrains-ide

The IDE has autocomplete for code but doesn't have an automatic completion function for words in the comments, like the following comment:

```
/**
* this is a comment
* this is a co
*
*/
```

When I type `co` I want to get tips in some words that like: `com`, `comm`, `comment` ……

Is there any plugin that can do this?

Comment: You can use `Code | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word` actions for that -- https://i.imgur.com/BTu0A2S.png -- it should complete the word in place with no pop up / list to choose from. Just invoke it again (see the link below) to get another match completed. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/install/intellij), although it uses a lot of memory and slows down your computer.